# How to handle big chunks of text

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Until now I have used

```
<Label Text="Some Text"</Label>
```

to present text for the user. However, I was wondering if this is the correct way to render big premade text strings with bullets etc. or if there is another, more neat way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a `WebView` in the past with a transparent background. That allows as much markup as needed and is fairly easy to do. Though I have also just used a simple `Label` and added a bunch of `\n`'s and `\t`'s to make it look like a formatted document. I think it depends on your preference, the layout you are putting the element in, and if the text will be dynamically pulled or not.

There are also markdown plugins you can add that will format mark down text so thats another option. Something like [this](https://github.com/SuavePirate/MarkdownTextView) (I have not tried this plugin myself btw).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to play around with it. Though, coming from web, label seems almost illegal to use for this purpose :-)

Comment: @JeppeChristensen Haha yes I'm with you on that. Its like putting an entire web page in a `<span>` or something.